# change all values of a list of unknown initial shape

Tags: python, list

what i want is to change all elements in a list with an unknown initial shape, so i made this helper function, but
is there a better (shorter) way, or a builtin to do this?

and also another question on the side, where is the best place to store such a function >if< there is no builtin, instead of copy paste it in every file, or project

```
def getNextList():
    yield [1]
    yield [[1,2],3]
    yield [[1,2,[3]], [4,5],6]

def change(next_list, function):
    for i, e in enumerate(next_list):
        if(isinstance(e, int)):
            next_list[i] = function(next_list[i])
        else: change(e, function)

for next_list in getNextList():
    change(next_list, lambda x: x+1)
    print(next_list)
```

desired output:

```
 [2] 
 [[2, 3], 4] 
 [[2, 3, [4]], [5, 6], 7]
```

Edit:
@Colin Schoen is is not a duplicate of your tagged question, because iterating twice would just give me an Error

i guess the solution i posted, or the version of @blhsing which is indeed shorter, is the only one for that particular problem, but if i stick to it, what would be the way to have that function available across different projects without duplicating it?

Comment: There is no built in way. What's wrong with your way? Why must it be shorter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Map" a nested list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080828/map-a-nested-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `change` return a generator expression instead so that it can make use of the returning value of the recursive call:

```
def change(next_list, function):
    return (list(change(e, function)) if isinstance(e, list) else function(e) for e in next_list)
```

so that:

```
for changed_list in change(getNextList(), lambda x: x+1):
    print(changed_list)
```

outputs:

```
[2]
[[2, 3], 4]
[[2, 3, [4]], [5, 6], 7]
```

As for your second part of the question, you can store this function in a separate module, such as `utils.py`, inside a directory that is part of your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, so that any project of yours can simply do `from utils import change` to make this function available in the namespace.